# can we store negative (-) and plus (+) sign numbers in mysql varchar column

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store numbers with plus or minus signs in a varchar column in mysql. 
I am using php.

+100 saves 100

100+ the insert fails

-100 its ok shows -100

100- the insert fails

Comment: Please show your code/SQL queries.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/732033/1

Comment: A number with neither a `+` or a `-` is implicitly a positive number; so why not use the number-type and infer the `+` from the absence of a `-`?

Comment: Why are you using `VARCHAR` for this?  Why not one of MySQL's [numeric data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-types.html)?

Comment: use varchar or even big int

Comment: Adding values inside quotes(') will work, if column is Varchar

Comment: Why store a number in a `VARCHAR`? Would an integer be better

Comment: the client want such as 100+ , 100- , +100 , -100, some time sign on right and some time on left. so I the INT datatype will not work.

Comment: @ChiragB here is my code how to add ('): <input type="text" name="hp" value="<?php echo $hp; ?>"/>

Comment: @ChiragB this gives error: <input type="text" name="hp" value="<?php echo "'".$hp;."'" ?>"/>

Comment: @JohnWoo how to inclose the value $hp in single Quotes. <input type="text" name="hp" value="<?php echo $hp; ?>"/>

Comment: @Muhammad Take the value from textbox,and while inserting it into mySQL add quotes,

Comment: @JohnWoo  its working, now I can save the value to database like '+100', but it displays 100 when I display using echo.

Comment: Store the number as a number, not as a string; convert to a number on input, format for output

Answer (score 1):

According to the cases you specified, most probably you have not added the quotes to the values and MySQL treats the values as integers and then converts them to VARCHAR (in your first and third cases). Please check your INSERT-statement and add the quotes to value:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('$value')";
```

And of course it is better to use numeric datatypes for storing such values.